# HighCharts DataLabels Overlap

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/nUCBj/1/

How can I prevent the datalabels from overlapping?  I have tried using the formatter option and positioning the dataLabel using CSS position/top/bottom, etc...  The datalabels are required.  I can't just use the tooltip in it's place :-)

Thank you,

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: true,
                borderRadius: 1,
                useHTML: true,
                padding: 1
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
                        name: 'test',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4] },{
            name: 'test2',
        data: [31, 80, 106.4, 22, 150, 17, 135.7, 14, 230, 181, 9, 54]
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data attribute in the series can be passed in as an array of objects instead of as an array of numbers.  Each object can define it's own dataLabels options (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data).  For the first series you can align the points to the left, and the second to the right so they do not overlap.

Comment: Ok, I followed your advice and the link.  Unfortunately, what I'm working on pushes the data into the graph with both an X and Y coordinate.  So the data looks like this [[x, y], [x, y], etc...].  How can I apply the DataLabels attribute to that?  I tried it on JFiddle but couldn't get it to work.  Here is my link: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vm34W/1/)

Comment: It should would be nice if I could do something like this instead (but only if it work): [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nUCBj/2/)

Comment: You can see in this example how to define these, only shows one series but you can extrapolate http://jsfiddle.net/NqEc2/